# Integer overflow on equivalent expressions?

Tags: c++, multiplication, integer-overflow

I am doing [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/) questions and I'm getting an overflow when calculating the multiplication of two large numbers a certain way, but no overflow when I calculate it in what to me seems to be completely equivalent code.

`maxDiffH` and `maxDiffV` are both very large integers. And the answer of the question is the multiplication of those two integers modded by `7+(10^9)`.

This piece of code fails at the multiplication line with the message:
`Line 60: Char 32: runtime error: signed integer overflow: 999999998 * 999999998 cannot be represented in type 'int' (solution.cpp)`
`SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior prog_joined.cpp:69:32`

```
        long mod = pow(10,9)+7;
        long result = maxDiffV *maxDiffH;
        result = result % mod;
        return result;
```

While this other piece of code works just fine

```
        long result = maxDiffH;
        result *= maxDiffV;
        long div = 1e9+7;
        result = result%div;
        return result;
```

I thought calculating result in a single line by multiplying `maxDiffH` and `maxDiffV` right away would be equivalent to updating result.

Can anyone explain why one version works and the other one doesn't?

Comment: Multiply two `int`s and you get an `int` even if you assigh to something bigger afterward.

Comment: Unrelated: `pow(10,9)+7;` involves some risk. Compilers are pretty smart these days and will probably give you what you want, but if it doesn't you may find the number produced by `pow` is something like 999999999.999999, and that will be truncated to 999999999, not rounded up to 1000000000.

Comment: See the [differences](https://godbolt.org/z/eGe97MaYG) between the assembly code produced from these two functions.

Comment: you need to `(long)` one of them

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone in the comments.

The easy answer to this (as it was mentioned in the comments) is that in the first version, I'm multiplying a pair of int variables, and the compiler tries to store (unsuccessfully) that calculation as an int before assigning it to my variable `result`.

The second case, is equivalent to typecasting `maxDiffH` to a long and storing it in `result`, to later multiply a long with an int which is stored temporarily as a long before updating my variable.

I hope that helps any rookie like me out there :)